# Boost.Asio on Android failing with Service Not Found (Boost 1.53; NDK r8e)

Tags: android, boost, cross-platform, boost-asio

I am trying to build a cross-platform application for Android and iOS and have chosen to use Boost to simplify communication and to parse the JSON from the response. Everything works fine in iOS, but Android fails with "service not found" error, or "host not found (authoritative)" if I change the query to `query(server, "");`.

I pulled the code out of my application and simplified it to what was throwing the error and this is what I have:

```
...
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
std::string server = "<server_address>";

// Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(server, "http");
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query,ec);

if (ec)
{
    return env->NewStringUTF(ec.message().c_str());
}
```

I am using Android NDK r8e (64-bit) and Boost version 1.53 (latest releases as of writing). I have used https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android with slight modification to work with the 64-bit NDK (see https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android/pull/28) for building the required Boost libraries.

I will be modifying this to work with `async_resolve`, which is what the iOS version is using, once I can get this part working.

**Edit:**

I noticed I had forgotten to update the Android Manifest file, so I added 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`, but I still get the same errors. Am I simply missing something else in the manifest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the OS can't figure out which port stands for `http`. On most POSIX-compliant systems this mapping is done in `/etc/services` file, and if `http` line is missing there, you'll get "service not found" error.

I don't know whether Android has this file or not (older versions didn't support it at all, the services were hardcoded in `bionic`), but if you get the above error, the only workaround is to set the desired port manually:

```
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), yourHost, "80");
```

Comment: I have tried this and I get an error during ndk-build.`error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::flags' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @DemonGyro Oh, sorry, the port should be string. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: another version of constructor would be
asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("your.host.com", "80");
or
asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("your.host.com", "443");
for https